# Rails 3 Join question

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey there,
  i have a user model, a discovered_locations model and a boss_locations model.

A boss_location is the static representation of a boss location. A discovered location is (user_id, boss_location_id).

What is a nice way(even better if a scope is involved i guess), to get a join of the user boss locations and discovered locations ?

That is, i want to get a join on the boss locations. I want all the boss locations, either discovered or not, but i want to also know if they are discovered.

How would you do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple and efficient way would be to add a counter_cache to the boss_location / discovered_location relationship. That way you could query without joins and get the same results:

```
class BossLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :discovered_locations

  scope :discovered, where(["#{quoted_table_name}.discovered_locations_count > ?", 0])
  scope :undiscovered, where(["#{quoted_table_name}.discovered_locations_count = ?", 0])

  def discovered?
    self.discovered_locations_count > 0
  end
end

class DiscoveredLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :boss_location, :counter_cache => true
end
```

If you wanna stick with the join route, you'd have to do something like this:

```
class BossLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :discovered_locations

  scope :with_discovery_status, joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN discovered_locations ON boss_locations.id = discovered_locations.boss_location_id").group("boss_locations.id").select("boss_locations.*, count(discovered_locations.id) AS discover_status")

  def discovered?
    self[:discover_status].present? && self['discover_status'].to_i > 0 || self.discovered_locations.size > 0
  end
end
```

The LOJ will keep all the records but the count() in the select will give you the status flag you wanted. Hopefully that's what you're looking for.